# 301 redirect forms aspx to mvc page using web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-301

Firstly, I have searched SO and google'd no luck

I am trying to redirect an existing forms websites Product.aspx page to the new MVC2.net page for the new version of the website.

I want to achieve this using the web.config as the example below:

```
<location path="Products.aspx">
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.address.com/Products/Page" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
```

I believe the page specified in location path= needs to physically exist which it doesn't in the new mvc website for this to work.

Is there a way it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. It's just that the `<system.webServer>` section is only read and interpreted by IIS 7.0 and higher. It won't work with Cassini nor IIS 6.0.

Comment: Yes I am testing on the webserver but does it make a difference if the page doesn't physically exist in my project?